# Only in promise chain: "Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined"

Tags: javascript, flowtype

[Please refer to this example.](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swoAKAQzAH4AuMAQQCdnKBPAHgGd9nDsAcwB8ASjABvVGDDUAvLLAAfJWADaAXQDc02QDoAtpQAOYYMDAAJAKbNrYQvgfcwcANa67+TM1IAFZjgDQm5rPTtuOBgAN2tyUV0ASD18AAtrbHJ4sDlhfSNjcXMwABVLACUAeQB1AGUAGjBqywBNGlQAX3QAoJCw3DhAzCJsOKw8IhJwKloGFjYuXn4hMUkzC0YofFsHPBhMABMBQTAAI33rU8JmA7AD6ygBR2JsXXlFFXVtXXZCaxhbpRDCZ1k1Bm5uJ1RPEgA)

```
function f(a ?: Array<string>) {
  a = a || [];
  a.map // Here it is ok
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => a.map) // THROWS, WHY?
}
```

Comment: Probably because it doesn't apply the refinement inside the lambda.

Comment: @SLaks It does. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow's type refinements are conservative. This means that it [invalidates them](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#refinement-invalidations) aggressively when it can't be sure that they will hold.

In this case, Flow sees that `a` has been reassigned so that it must not be `null`/`undefined`. However, it does not do the analysis to know that is is *always* going to be `null`/`undefined` -- as far as it knows here, some later assignment could re-assign it to `null`/`undefined`.

It also doesn't know when the callback passed to `.then` will be called. So, it conservatively invalidates the refinement.

Note that this issue is not specific to `Promise`s. It will happen whenever a non-const variable has a refinement applied to it, and it is later used in a closure. Inside the closure, the refinement will be dropped.

The simple workaround is to use `const`. Then, Flow knows that any type refinement that is applied will always hold, since the variable can never be reassigned:

```
function f(a_ ?: Array<string>) {
  const a = a_ || [];
  a.map // Here it is ok
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => a.map) // THROWS, WHY?
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That is because in your function definition you have:

`function f(a ?: Array<string>) {`

that means `a`'s type is an array of strings **but it is nullable** (`?:`). Its value can be null (or undefined).

Although from your code it is evident that `a` is overridden by an empty array if its `null` (or undefined). But its type still remains a nullable array of strings.

When the compiler tries to compile this line:

`.then(() => a.map) // THROWS, WHY?`

it thinks that `a` might be null (or undefined) and so complains with an error.

If you remove the question mark `?` in your function parameter type, the compiler knows that `a` cannot be null and thus **it works!**

PS: If the need be you can move `a = a || [];` to the function that calls function `f`.

Comment: No; Flow is smart enough to know that `a = a || [];` refines the type of `a` to no longer include `null`.  That's why the first `a.map` is fine.  The problem is that this flow analysis does not include closures.